# Heading is messed up in Microsoft Word 16

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

In one of my word document heading 2 is missed up. It shows black box where the number (1.1) should be, see the attachment.

I tried to reformat it but it doesn't seem to work. How do I fix it?

[Heading 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8SMR.png)

Comment: Put your cursor on the heading just right of the black box. Use the left arrow key on your keyboard to move left until the black box turns grey. Use the keyboard combination ctrl+shift+s, the dialog "Apply Styles" should appear. In this box, click "reapply"

Comment: I'm using windows keyboard so keys are mapped differently. Is there any menu where I can see Apply Style after left key?

Comment: The question has already been addressed and answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/238077/word-heading-number-blacked-out

Answer (score 0):

In Mac Word the keyboard shortcut of Command+Option+2 will reapply the Heading 2 style to the selected text.

There are a couple of ways to find out what keyboard shortcuts are available in Word for the Mac (versions 2019, 2016, and Office 365):

1. Do a web search on "[Keyboard shortcuts in Word for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-for-mac-3256d48a-7967-475d-be81-a6e3e1284b25#PickTab=Newer_versions)" and it will take you to a Microsoft Support article on the subject. The article also includes shortcuts for the Mac Office 2011 version.
2. From the Menu Bar in Word, choose `Tools > Customize Keyboard...` and you can look up the various functions of Word and see the keyboard shortcuts that are assigned to them.

Comment: Command+Option+2 does nothing but messes up all style even more.