# Weird black rectangle in Word's headings

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to build a Word template. It was working perfectly. I saved the document and opened it on another computer and I saw this:

[image]

All the sections were replaced with a weird black rectangle.

On the `Define new Multilevel list` I don't see `Chapitre 2` but an empty field with a small dot pixel on the top left (in the `Enter formatting for number:` section).

I cannot delete it or remove it. How can I fix this?

I've uploaded a minimal `.docx` file in base64: https://pastebin.com/rF9jgWCs

Note that https://superuser.com/a/516480/374513 doesn't solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: Can't you upload the file in straight docx format using Dropbox/OneDrive etc?

Comment: @harrymc https://www.dropbox.com/s/pi9rsh33agitwqo/weird.docx?dl=0

Comment: I would record your desired settings for your headings, then replace the Headings by updating them to match the Normal style, then restore them to your desired configuration.  Then I would go back and apply the attributes I wanted to the heading style.

Answer (score 1):

### Here is a short macro to repair this from Word MVP Doug Robbins:

```
Sub FixNumberingIssuesInLists()
'Macro originally created by MVP Doug Robbins
'Modified by MVP Stefan Blom, February 2020
Dim LT As ListTemplate
Dim i As ListLevel
For Each LT In ActiveDocument.ListTemplates
    For Each i In LT.ListLevels
        If i.NumberStyle <> wdListNumberStyleBullet Then
            i.Font.Reset
        End If
    Next i
Next LT
End Sub
```

I tried it with your sample and it works fine.

[Microsoft Community Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/black-box-displayed-instead-of-section-number/74a3fe46-17b5-441f-8f44-00469627eb92)

- [Using macros](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/installing_employing_macros.html) by Greg Maxey
- [Installing macros from forums](http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm) by Graham Mayor

Answer (score 0):

You have managed to create a very weird style, creating
a header without numbering.

Here is how to undo the damage:

- Click the line "Weird is weird!"
- Click twice the numbering icon in the Paragraph group.
  The first click will make it into non-numbered and the second
  will remake it into numbered, but now with the right number `1`
- In the Home pane click the bottom-right icon in the Styles group
- Click the drop-down button to the right of "Heading 1;Chapitre"
  and select "Update Heading 1 to Match Selection"
- Weird is now not so weird any more.